# How can I get the exact compiler command line from visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, linker

I have to port the build of a DLL from building in Visual Studio to another build system.  The DLL solution wasn't made by me and it's got lots of modified command line switches etc.  I've copied the compiler/linker options from Visual Studio's

Project Properties -> Config Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line
Project Properties -> Config Properties -> Linker -> Command Line

However, when I build the DLL from my other build tool (and I've also tried a simple batch file) the DLL is a slightly different size and causes a crash sometimes when the DLL is used (which the one built by vis studio doesn't do).

So my question is:

1. Is there a better way to see the exact command line than what's in vis studio properties page?
2. Does Vis Studio do any crazy magic beyond what's happening on the command line (I hope the answer to this is no!) :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something to keep in mind is that command-line options can be set per-source file too, not just per-project, which may be what you're missing.

One way to see everything that's going on is to look at the build log. At the end of the build in the Output view, you should see a line like:

> Build log was saved at "file path".

Ctrl-click the file path in the output view and it will load the log file, and you should see all of the command lines for each file.

**Update:**

This answer was for Visual Studio 2008. You no longer get the link in the output window in newer versions of Visual Studio. Instead you have to navigate to the build directory for your project to see the log file. See here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651643.aspx

Actually that link is slightly wrong. The log file has a .log extension rather than .txt.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I figured out my problem from the build log.  I had all the compile/link switches correct but I hadn't added the manifest to the DLL which was making it fail to link at run time.  I'm from a linux background so wasn't too aware of DLLs and all their intricacies.

Comment: I don't see it. All I get is a link to the exe that is created, with no "build log was saved at file path" part.

Comment: as @BryceSandlund states, the build output does not always give the log file path (I doubt it even writes a log). However you can have a verbose / debug output in your UI: menu Tools > Options; Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity. Personally I'd advise to go with a 'Detailed' log, usually it should give you the desired information.

Comment: @DamianVogel - this answer was for VS2008. You still get a log file in newer versions in your build directory, which contains the full command-line, as long as your build log verbosity is still set to "Normal" (default). It's a lot easier to read than the "Detailed" information in the output window if you just want to see the command line. I updated my answer.

Comment: Cant find that log file with any extensions of .log or .txt on vs2019.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2019 build, the log files are named *.tlog under <proj_dir>\x64\release\<proj_name.tlog>\CL.command.1.tlog